# How to stop "Tor can't help you if you use it wrong" warning?

Tags: startup

When starting Tor I get this warning:

```
[notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
```

Is it important, and how can I disable that?

Answer (score 2):

The log message you mentioned is just a default log message that gets printed out on every start (doesn't depend on certain config. See: https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/core/mainloop/main.c#n3488).

Unfortunately you can't disable *just* this message: To remove it you'll have to disable all logging in your `torrc` file.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, let me try this differently.

Your original log message contained a line indicating that your `/etc/tor/torrc` file did not exist. This is the file where you configure settings for Tor. It is created for you automatically, so this was either the very first time you ever ran this Tor instance, or you deleted it, in either case, this was the only evidence in that log snippet of anything amiss and thus the reason I suggest you create said file.

That message displays before any configuration file is loaded, and every time you start Tor. It is not an error, it is, both by its text and the contents of the URL explicitly mentioned in that line, an admonishmenrt about non-tor and even non-technical behavioral changes required to use to anonymously.

This is a startup message, it does not indicate anything is TECHNICALLY wrong. As such you can't suppress it, and there is no reason to.

However, as you have apparently not read the provided url, and in fact violated some of it's suggestions by dumping your logs here before someone edited them away, you should probably heed this message.

References:
 - https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
 - http://lmgtfy.com/?q=%22Tor+can%27t+help+you+if+you+use+it+wrong!%22